# Moving a circle using a slider in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, slider

I am trying to create a program which has the ability to move a circle that I located in it's center with using a slider. What I can't figure out is how to connect the circle to the slider so that it moves when the slider is moved. 
Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I have:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        //Definisanje Hedera
        Label Seminarski = new Label("");
        Button Reset = new Button("Reset");
        Reset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            }
        });
        HBox HBoxHeader = new HBox();
        HBoxHeader.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        HBoxHeader.setSpacing(10);
        HBoxHeader.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff;");
        HBoxHeader.getChildren().addAll(Seminarski, Reset);
        //Kraj Hedera

        //Definisanje Lopte
        Circle Lopta = new Circle(10, Color.RED);
        //Kraj Lopte

        //Definisanje Slajdera
        Slider Slajder = new Slider();
        //Kraj Slajdera

        Lopta.rateProperty().bind(Slajder.valueProperty());

        //Definisanje Futera
        HBox HBoxFooter = new HBox();
        HBoxFooter.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        HBoxFooter.setSpacing(10);
        HBoxFooter.getChildren().addAll(Slajder);
        //Kraj Futera

        //Dodavanje u BorderPane
        root.setTop(HBoxHeader);
        root.setCenter(Lopta);
        root.setBottom(HBoxFooter);
        //Kraj Dodavanja

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

This is what I tried `Lopta.rateProperty().bind(Slajder.valueProperty())`. but there is an error.

This is what the program looks like:
[image]

Comment: You should show some code, and show what you have actually tried in order to do this. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will post the code as soon as I can, im not by the computer right now.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: An example of [adjusting layouts using sliders](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2724651).  You can adjust the implementation to base it on centerX/centerY properties of the circle rather than layoutX/layoutY properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use BorderPane. It limits your nodes layout control. Also, your variable naming convention is not recommend. In this little app, I made the root a VBox and added a Pane with the circle, a button, and a slider. I didn't use bind because I haven't worked with it much. I used a value change listener that moves the circle when the slider's value change.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaFXApplication39 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle(10, Color.RED);
        circle.setCenterX(10);
        circle.setCenterY(10);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setMinHeight(200);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("reset");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();

        root.getChildren().add(pane);

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((
                ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val,
                Number new_val) -> {
            circle.setCenterX(new_val.doubleValue());
        });

        root.getChildren().add(slider);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

When dealing with a slider's change listener, you have three objects. You have the ObservableValue ov, the Number old_val, and the Number new_val. If you use a System.out.println() statement inside the listener, you will notice that every time the slider is moved the old_val displays the value the slider moved from and the new_val displays the value the slider moved to. In the code above we are only concerned with the new_val.

To move a circle with the slider,  You need need to set the circle's location based on the slider's new_value. <- This is done using circle.setCenterX(new_value);

You should go [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/slider.htm) For a better explanation.

Comment: Hi. I tested the code on my computer and it's pretty much what I wanted to do, but I am unfamiliar (I'm a newbie) with the code that is within the listener. If it isn't a bother could you explain what the following code does?
 
`slider.valueProperty().addListener((
                ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val,
                Number new_val) -> {
            circle.setCenterX(new_val.doubleValue());
        });`